# What postgres data type should I use for sql that returns a big decimal in Rails

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, bigdecimal

I have an app where I'm trying to generate a dollar amount into a new AR record called Metric.  I've written the following simple class method to generate a new metric method:

```
  def self.last_year
    m = Metric.new
    m.name = Figaro.env.company_name
    m.metric_type = "Last Year"
    m.amount = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select sum(dst_amt::DECIMAL) from distributions where dst_code like 'COL%' and dst_posted_date::DATE BETWEEN (select (date_trunc('month', current_date)) - INTERVAL '13 Month') and (select (date_trunc('month', current_date)) - INTERVAL '366 Day')")
    m.save
  end
```

This basically works and creates the Metric record, however the amount when I output it in the console after running this method is:

```
<BigDecimal:10173c470,'0.0',9(18)>
```

When I run the SQL in Postico or Navicat raw the number that results is: `1043.88`.  So my question(s) are:

1.) Based off of this query and raw result, what datatype in postgres should I be using for the amount field?  I tried decimal but it writes the output as a BigDecimal and I can't read it, I've also tried float, but when I run the class method it gives me a NoMethodError `to_f` on the class.

2.) Is this the best way to run the SQL from within the class?  My SQL is correct when I run it via Navicat or Postico, but in the class I output a big decimal.

My ultimate goal is to generate metric records on multiple servers then somehow get them over to a target server maybe via a 2nd dbase connection or simply export to csv, scp over, and import via csv on the target server.  Really this should be an API type of scenario but I don't have that sort of time and need to just get something working today hopefully.

If my code and/or question is not clear, please let me know and I'll edit.

**Update**
So when I try to break this method down in the console I run this:

`a = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select sum(dst_amt::DECIMAL) from distributions where dst_code like 'COL%' and dst_posted_date::DATE BETWEEN (select (date_trunc('month', current_date)) - INTERVAL '13 Month') and (select (date_trunc('month', current_date)) - INTERVAL '366 Day')")`

Which gives me: `=> #<PG::Result:0x0000010d84c958 status=PGRES_TUPLES_OK ntuples=1 nfields=1 cmd_tuples=1>`

Then from the console I call `a[0]` I get the hash value of `=> {"sum"=>"1101.88"}`

So I guess my question has expanded.  Am I even calling the SQL properly to populate the amount field in my method?  And if so, how do I parse this output to return a decimal of 1101.88 (or whatever the result is) to the amount column which is a decimal type field?

**Update again**

Here is my refactored method

```
  def self.last_year_mtd
    m = Metric.new
    m.name = Figaro.env.company_name
    m.metric_type = "Last Year MTD"
    sql = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select sum(dst_amt::DECIMAL) from distributions where dst_code like 'COL%' and dst_posted_date::DATE BETWEEN (select (date_trunc('month', current_date)) - INTERVAL '13 Month') and (select (date_trunc('month', current_date)) - INTERVAL '366 Day')")
    total = sql[0]["sum"].to_s
    m.amount = total
    m.save
  end
```

So when I run this from the console it creates a new Metric record.  So if I create two records I need to do arithmetic on it.  So I tried this out.

Ran `last_year_mtd` from the console and a similar method which has a different query and generates a different big decimal.

Then I assign `a = Metric.first` and `b = Metric.last` to get two different objects.

Then I do the arithmetic: `2.1.1 :012 > (b.amount - a.amount).to_s
 => "1396.4"`

This looks to be working.  Calling `.to_s` on the arithmetic seems to have done the trick.

I'm sure this method could be cleaner, so if anyone has ideas on a refactor I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a decimal.

If you need to display the value then use to_s to convert it to a string, or to_f to convert it to float. However some decimals cannot be accurately represented as a float, and if all you want to do is look at the value then a string representation is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, I switched back to decimal as my data type.  Please see my refactor and results, let me know how I can improve it.

Comment: Do you not have models for dst_code and dst_posted_date? I'm not anti-SQL at all, but this seems like it could be expressed in Rails/ActiveRecord. That "INTERVAL '366 Day'" will be incorrect for leap years, by the way.

Comment: No, there's no model.  We are SQL heavy with our app otherwise I'd be doing this all Rails/AR.  And good catch on the 366 day interval.  I didn't take that into account.